# GEO_PERFORMANCE_REPORT query is null

Tags: google-ads-api

ReportQuery query =
                new ReportQuery.Builder()
                        .fields(
                                "CityCriteriaId", "Clicks", "Impressions","Ctr","AverageCpc","AveragePosition","CountryCriteriaId"
                        )
                        .from(ReportDefinitionReportType.GEO_PERFORMANCE_REPORT)
                        .where("CampaignStatus ").in("ENABLED")
                        .during(ReportDefinitionDateRangeType.LAST_MONTH)
                        .build();
query is null

ReportQuery query =
                new ReportQuery.Builder()
                        .fields(
                                "AccountDescriptiveName",
                                "CampaignName",
                                "CampaignId",
                                "CampaignStatus",
                                "Conversions",
                                "ConversionRate",
                                "InteractionRate",
                                "Interactions",
                                "Cost",
                                "Ctr",
                                "Date",
                                "Impressions",
                                "Clicks")
                        .from(ReportDefinitionReportType.CAMPAIGN_PERFORMANCE_REPORT)
                        //   .where("Status").in("ENABLED")
                        .during(ReportDefinitionDateRangeType.LAST_30_DAYS)
                        .build();
query success

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: The csv data returned by the performance data of the report campaign-level location is empty, but the csv returned by the campaign performance data query has data, I don’t know why.